# What iOS VNC client has the least lag?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, screen-sharing

I've downloaded VNC Viewer on my iPad. I have noticed that it takes about 10 seconds for the iPad screen to update, in order to reflect the current Macbook screen. This is on the lowest quality setting in VNC Viewer.

I understand that the update speed is a function of the speed of my internet connection. Both the Macbook and the iPad are connected to the internet via WiFi.

However, is there an iOS app that updates faster? In other words, is there an app that offers a lower picture quality? I am comfortable with losing picture quality in exchange for less lag.

I do not need the ability to control or manipulate the Mac. I just need the ability to view the Mac's screen. The picture quality does not have to be particularly clear.

---

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

<sub>iOS 10.3.2</sub>

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at: [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com) (Main Web Site link.)

You can download the macOS version from there.

For iOS 5.1.1 or later. Compatible with iPad: [iTunes Preview of NoMachine](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nomachine/id874286563?mt=8)

I haven't used it between my Mac and iDevice, but do use it between my Mac and Linux Media Server. It's free and it works great for my needs.

Comment: Perfect recommendation! NoMachine is significantly faster than VNC Viewer (on the same internet connection). The screen update latency on my iPad is now under 1 second. Amazing. Thank you.